# Callbacks in Sammy

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

I have this peice of code - I just need to add a class on a DOM element which will be rendered in the template. However, this fails to work!

```
    this.get('#/:post_id', function(context){
            context.app.swap('');
         this.load('/post/' +  this.params['post_id'])
             .then(function(candidates){
                  $.each(candidates[1], function(i, candidate){
                      context.render("static/templates/candidate.template", {candidate:candidate})
                     .appendTo(context.$element());
             });
         })
        .then(function(){
            $('h3').addClass('custom_class');
         });
```

Candidate.template:

```
<div>
  <h3>Name : <%= candidate.name %> </h3>
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to Sammy, so take this with a grain of salt.  I think it is failing because your first .then() doesn't return anything (like the context), which means the next .then() has nothing to work on.

Does something like this work ?

```
this.get('#/:post_id', function(context){
        context.app.swap('');
     this.load('/post/' +  this.params['post_id'])
         .then(function(candidates){
              $.each(candidates[1], function(i, candidate){
                  context.render("static/templates/candidate.template", {candidate:candidate})
                 .appendTo(context.$element());
         });
         return context;
     })
    .then(function(){
        $('h3').addClass('custom_class');
     });
});
```